# Why should people post on this site?

Tags: discussion

I have been a part of this site for a number of years now and was thinking to myself the other day... Why exactly do I post here? This is not a forum, extended discussions are actively discouraged.

I have spent years adding content to this site with not a hint of any monetary value for all the content I have provided. Moderators don't even get a salary or a stipend for all there efforts, and still there is a company built on the work of other people, who for all there efforts go unpaid?

At least, YouTube has given some content creators money. There is still ways to monetize your YouTube efforts, but here there are none.

Why cannot a couple of dollars be given to good answer / question or some sort of monetary reward for hitting certain reps, the company makes money, why shouldn't we?

Comment: "*Why exactly do I post here?*" - Out of the goodness of your heart...

Comment: I get bucket-loads of value from the content I have provided. I no longer have to provide portfolios to convince customers I know my stuff, for example.

Comment: So @MartijnPieters, how is your COBOL going? ....

Comment: @rene: I have a separate junk folder for the recruiters that think I do Java or PHP or whathaveyounot, wanna go join them? :-)

Comment: @rene Hit and miss:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/Znh2B.jpg

Comment: As much as we contribute our knowledge, StackOverflow is a company. They built the platform for us, they paid their developers and invested in a business model. We are in no way entitled to their money. Not to mention all the horrible repercussions that would stem from paid answers. If you want to be paid for your teaching, become a teacher or do freelancing

Answer (score 10):

People post here to share knowledge.

The moment that people can earn money from posting here, earning money will become their priority - not sharing knowledge.

We've already got problems with people who post to gain points. Adding money to the mix would increase this problem by orders of magnitude.

Comment: Money doesn't care whether the answer is right or wrong - people who post for money won't, either. Unless they lose money from down votes - but then what happens to a post with a net negative score? Does the poster have to give the company money?

Comment: @MattGutting ...then we'd get even more drama about downvotes...

Answer (score 6):

The day Stack Overflow the company will start charging money from people in order to get answers or privileges, I'm out for good, without coming back. That's a promise.

One of the greatest powers of Stack Overflow platform is that it's ***free*** to use, thus making it equally accessible both to someone without a single penny in their pocket, and for someone with $50000000 in their bank account. Both of those people can use the platform **exactly in the same way**.

Comment: Wasn't the question about content creators retribution, instead?

Comment: @301 not clear enough from the question. "couple of dollars be given" doesn't say where those dollars will come from. If from the company, I'm still against it, but for different reasons indeed.